# EF 6 Database first Change table / column names

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am looking at EF (not done before but do understand c#) but I am finding it hard to change the names I have given tables and properties in the database to c# name.

I use prefix's for my database e.g. a user table will be called  "tblUsers" will have columns of "usrID" , "usrName" ... but in C# EF it looks like tblUsers.usrID / tblUsers.usrName which is not needed. I would like it to look like User.Id / User.Name. I have got it to do this by changing OnModelCreating to register the property name / table name but this means I cant easily update EF to match any changes I do in the database.

Does anyone have a good way of doing this so I can easily update the model?

Comment: Entity framework maps database object as an entity(class) in .edmx file.
So you cannot set different column name in database and different name in application.

Comment: I am able to set different names, its the refreshing the EF model that will wipe my settings which I dont want it to do, I just want it to add / change what I have done in the database.                 modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("tblUsers");

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(usr => usr.Id).HasColumnName("uID");

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but just with a couple tables.
What I do is to save and keep my modified partial classes apart and then exclude those tables from EF model generation.
Now I have to be aware from any changes on the database.